# column value parse json

Tags: python, json, pandas

ive got data drame

```
json = {'contexts_ru_andata_master_cookies_1': {0: [{'_ym_uid': '1664978572350562652'}],
  1: [{'_ym_uid': '1664978577951178500'}],
  2: [{'_ym_uid': '1631015476823239589'}],
  3: [{'_ym_uid': '1664945479855475653'}],
  4: [{'_ym_uid': '1663327749550707020'}],
  6: [{'_ym_uid': '1664978547593809275'}],
  7: [{'_ym_uid': '16649783691007078342'}],
  8: [{'_ym_uid': '1662551949642530804'}]}}


pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json)
```

i need to get numeric value from cell, any help will be appreciated.
like 1664978577951178500 and etc

Comment: Like... `df['contexts_ru_andata_master_cookies_1'][1][0]['_ym_uid']`? I'm not sure what you are asking. It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve. That dataframe structure really doesn't make much sense given your "json" data. It's also odd that you would drag a dataframe into this as `json['contexts_ru_andata_master_cookies_1'][1][0]['_ym_uid']` outputs what you want. Can you explain more about what you are trying to do with this data?

Comment: i mean i need only digits from json up to every value )

Answer (score 1):

It's not a corret json string, you can use "re" to match it.

```
import re

json = '''{'contexts_ru_andata_master_cookies_1': {0: [{'_ym_uid': '1664978572350562652'}],
  1: [{'_ym_uid': '1664978577951178500'}],
  2: [{'_ym_uid': '1631015476823239589'}],
  3: [{'_ym_uid': '1664945479855475653'}],
  4: [{'_ym_uid': '1663327749550707020'}],
  6: [{'_ym_uid': '1664978547593809275'}],
  7: [{'_ym_uid': '16649783691007078342'}],
  8: [{'_ym_uid': '1662551949642530804'}]}}'''

res = re.finditer(r'\'[0-9]*\'', json)
cookies_l = []
for i in res:
    cookies_l.append(i.group()[1:-1])

print(cookies_l)
```

This is output：

```
['1664978572350562652', '1664978577951178500', '1631015476823239589', '1664945479855475653', '1663327749550707020', '1664978547593809275', '16649783691007078342', '1662551949642530804']
```

Answer (score 0):

df['_ym_uid'] = df['contexts_ru_andata_master_cookies_1'].str[0].str[0].apply(lambda x : x['_ym_uid'])

that was the answer